# Sending in JSON info but I recieve this error: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 3, position 1

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 3, position 1.

Any idea why this is happening? When I use the exact same code and send it to parse (for example) it works but when I try to send it to my own domain it doesnt work. Is this backend related?

```
static public async Task<JObject> signupUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var postData = new Dictionary <string, string> ();

        postData.Add ("username", username);
        postData.Add ("password", password);

        var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = await httpClientRequest.PostAsync("http://myadress.com/_put.php", content);
        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (resultString);
        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

        return  jsonResult;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (jsonResult);

    }
```

MY backend code:

```
<?php 

 $value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

 $mysql_pekare= new mysqli ("serv", "user","pass", "db");

 if(!empty($value)) {

 $stmt = $mysql_pekare->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`) VALUES(?,?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("ss", $value->username, $value->password);
 $stmt->execute();


 $stmt->close();

 $mysql_pekare->close();
 }


 ?>
```

Comment: So what's in `resultString`?

Comment: sec running it in my log

Comment: It appears to be "nothing" inside it when I run it in the log or it crashes before it has a chance to give a result in the log. var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString); is the code that crashes the whole thing

Comment: Well yes, you don't appear to be logging `resultString`... why not just run the code in the debugger and look that way?

Comment: I just added it. System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (resultString); if that is what you mean.

Comment: put the code in `try {}  catch() { throw; } `  you will get the exact exception with stack trace.

Comment: Yeah it reaches "Catch" if i do a return null; inside that function. if i do a "throw" inside that function it crashes with the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend (php) code doesn't seem to output anything (except maybe a few whitespaces). So it's no wonder that JObject can't parse it: it isn't json.

Comment: Okok. Yeah it seems like that is the problem. How do you think I should name my next post to go more in depth on how to solve it? "How do I adjust this PHP-backend code so the JObjects I am sending can be parsed?" Would that work?

Comment: I would use JSON instead of JObjects. But the real question is, what information do you want to send from the php backend to the c# frontend?

Comment: Once I upload the username + password I want to get the objectId/userId (that I have in my backend right now as AI (auto_increment so it manually gives me a unique ID) + a sessionToken (that I have not made yet) in return.

Comment: So when I run System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (jsonResult); in the log I will get the objectId + sessionToken. I am however very unsure how I should execute it right now.

Comment: As a test you can try returning/echoing a valid JSON string from your backend. Like "{ objectID: 123: sessionId: 'foobar' }"